# Java loading JAR dynamically: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, classloader

Let's say I have a main class App that loads all jars in the sub-directory *plugins* using a URLClassLoader:

```
public class App(){
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(File f : new File("plugins").listFiles()){
                URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + "plugins/" + f.getName() + ".jar" + "!/") };
                URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

                Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass(f.getName().toLowerCase()+"."+f.getName());
                cl.close();
                Plugin p = ((Plugin) clazz.newInstance());
        }
    }
}
```

All those jars contain a class that implements an interface Plugin.

```
+-- Main.jar
|    +-- App.class
|    +-- Plugin.class
|
+-- Plugins/
|    +-- PluginTest.jar
|         +-- plugintest
|              +-- PluginTest.class
|              +-- Two.class
```

That's all working fine if I write my code just in the PluginTest class. But as soon as I try to access Two from PluginTest, I'm getting a big error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: plugintest/Two
[...]
```

How should I load the the class correctly? Need help! Thanks.

Comment: Did you try with canonical name, e.g. `"plugintest.PluginTest"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not close your classloader.

Remove `cl.close();`statement.

Comment: Wow. That simple. Just can't believe but it works. Thanks for the great fast help!!!